# How to write a transitive predicate?

Tags: prolog

```pl
gt(ace,ten).
gt(ten,king).
gt(king,queen).
gt(queen,jack).

gt_(X,Y) :- 
    ( gt(X,Z1), gt(Z1,Z2), gt(Z2,Z3), gt(Z3,Y) ) ;
    ( gt(X,Z1), gt(Z1,Z2), gt(Z2,Y) ) ;
    ( gt(X,Z1), gt(Z1,Y) ) ;
    gt(X,Y) 
    .
```

`gt` means "greater than" and should be transitive. that means for example `gt_(ace, jack)` should yield `true`.

The above explicit implementation works but it is obviously unsatisfying to have all possible transitive indirection written out.

What would be a better more succinct way to write `gt_`?

Comment: Hint: Use a different predicate name than `gt` for your *rule*, to distinguish rule vs lookup, to avoid the infinite loop.

Comment: excellent point, this helped me sort out the stack problem and brought me back to my actual question. I'll rewrite the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your previous code was in the right direction except you would use a fact for the direct relations and the rule with different name for the recursive step:

```
gt(ace,ten).
gt(ten,king).
gt(king,queen).
gt(queen,jack).

gt_(X,Y) :- ( gt(X,Z1), gt_(Z1,Y) ) ; gt(X,Y) .
```

sample run:

```
?- gt_(X,Y).
X = ace,
Y = jack ;
X = ace,
Y = queen ;
X = ace,
Y = king ;
X = ten,
Y = jack ;
X = ten,
Y = queen ;
X = king,
Y = jack ;
X = ace,
Y = ten ;
X = ten,
Y = king ;
X = king,
Y = queen ;
X = queen,
Y = jack.

?- gt_(ten,ace).
false.
```